# How set background image for doc files when exporting nodes to Word in Drupal 7?

Tags: 7, nodes, theming

I used the [Node to Word](https://www.drupal.org/project/node_to_word) module in Drupal 7 to export nodes to Word. It doesn't have an official release for D7 yet, but there seems to be some [D7 version of it in GIT](http://cgit.drupalcode.org/node_to_word/tree/?h=7.x-1.x). I downloaded [this file](https://www.drupal.org/files/node_to_word-7.x-1.x.tar_.gz)) for it. This module supports writing template for a very convenient view mode.

How can I set the background image for the doc file when exporting a node to a doc?

I tried to use the background for the `<div>` sheathed same template but the export of the word, it has no effect.

Node template:

[image]

And result:

[image]

Comment: Can you even set a background image for paragraph directly in Word? You know, I never tried, but I would be kinda surprised if worked. For page, yes (borders, "textures" etc), but paragraph?

Answer (score 0):

The functionality you are looking for does not (as right now) exist in the version of the module you have linked to.

Therefore you will not be able to set the background image of the Word document without making modifications to the module.

This would be non-trivial as your modified module would have to do the following:

1. parse the CSS of the page to determine what image should be displayed
2. load the image and embed it in a format that Microsoft Word can understand
3. set the necessary tags in the Word document to use the embed image

Comment: you can get more detailed help or can show me a similar topic to solve this problem. Thank you very much